# Gulp stops watching without any errors

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, browser-sync, gulp-sass

I have a gulp file that is using the browsersync recipe for compiling my sass into css. It works great for the first few changes and my page hot reloads as expected. However, without warning, the gulp watch seemingly just quits. No matter the changes it refuses to acknowledge that the file has been modified. I can even undo/redo a background color and it will stop which proves there isn't a syntax error in my scss file.

Here is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');                                                                                    
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();                                                            
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;                                                                           
var sass = require('gulp-sass');                                                                               

gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {                                                                      
  browserSync.init({                                                                                           
    proxy: 'http://localhost:' + port,                                                                         
    open: false,                                                                                               
    notify: false                                                                                              
  });                                                                                                          

  gulp.watch('./sass/index.scss', ['sass'])                                                                    
  .on('error', console.log);                                                                                   


  gulp.watch('./**/*.hbs')                                                                                     
  .on('change', browserSync.reload)                                                                            
  .on('error', console.log);                                                                                   
});                                                                                                            

gulp.task('sass', function() {                                                                                 
  return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')                                                                          
  .pipe(sass().on('error', function(err) {                                                                     
    sass.logError(err);                                                                                        
    this.emit('end');                                                                                          
  }))                                                                                                          
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css'))                                                                             
  .pipe(browserSync.stream());                                                                                 
});                                                                                                            

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

And the versions being used:

```
"devDependencies": {                                                                                         
  "browser-sync": "^2.10.1",                                                                                 
  "gulp": "^3.9.0",                                                                                          
  "gulp-sass": "^2.1.1"                                                                                      
},
```

What's going on here?